# Savon OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wsdl, openssl, basic-authentication, savon

I'm using ruby 1.8.7 with rails 2.3.11, savon 1.1.0, wasabi 2.5.0, httpi 1.1.1, and httpclient 2.2.7

Whenever I run my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require File.expand_path(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '..', 'config', 'environment'))
require 'savon'

client = Savon::Client.new do |wdsl, http|
      wdsl.document = 'https://www.atmosfair.de:8443/service/AtmosfairEmissionService3?wsdl'
      http.auth.ssl.verify_mode = :none
      http.auth.basic "user", "password"
end

client.request :wdsl, "getFlightEmission" do
    soap.body = {
         :departure => "VIE",
         :arrival => "DUB"
    }
end
```

I get this:

> HTTPI executes HTTP GET using the httpclient adapter
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370/gems/httpclient-2.2.7/lib/httpclient/session.rb:300:in
>   `connect': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server
>   hello A: sslv3 alert unexpected message (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)
>
> from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370/gems/httpclient-2.2.7/lib/httpclient/session.rb:300:in `ssl_connect'
>   from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370/gems/httpclient-2.2.7/lib/httpclient/session.rb:757:in`connect'
>   from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370/gems/httpclient-2.2.7/lib/httpclient/timeout.rb:131:in `timeout'
>   from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370/gems/httpclient-2.2.7/lib/httpclient/session.rb:748:in`connect'
>   from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370/gems/httpclient-2.2.7/lib/httpclient/session.rb:606:in `query'
>   from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370/gems/httpclient-2.2.7/lib/httpclient/session.rb:161:in`query'
>   from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370/gems/httpclient-2.2.7/lib/httpclient.rb:1070:in  `do_get_block'
>   from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370/gems/httpclient-2.2.7/lib/httpclient.rb:873:in`do_request'
>   from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370/gems/httpclient-2.2.7/lib/httpclient.rb:966:in `protect_keep_alive_disconnected' 
>   from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370/gems/httpclient-2.2.7/lib/httpclient.rb:872:in`do_request'
>   from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370/gems/httpclient-2.2.7/lib/httpclient.rb:760:in `request'
>   from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370/gems/httpclient-2.2.7/lib/httpclient.rb:663:in`get'
>   from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370/gems/httpi-1.1.1/lib/httpi/adapter/httpclient.rb:24:in `get'
>   from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370/gems/httpi-1.1.1/lib/httpi/adapter/httpclient.rb:64:in`do_request'
>   from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370/gems/httpi-1.1.1/lib/httpi/adapter/httpclient.rb:23:in `get'
>   from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370/gems/httpi-1.1.1/lib/httpi.rb:86:in`get'
>   from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370/gems/httpi-1.1.1/lib/httpi.rb:193:in `with_adapter'
>   from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370/gems/httpi-1.1.1/lib/httpi.rb:84:in`get'
>   from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370/gems/savon-1.1.0/lib/savon/wasabi/document.rb:34:in `resolve_document'
>   from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370/gems/savon-1.1.0/lib/savon/wasabi/document.rb:15:in`xml'
>   from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370/gems/wasabi-2.5.0/lib/wasabi/document.rb:131:in `parse'
>   from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370/gems/wasabi-2.5.0/lib/wasabi/document.rb:118:in`parser'
>   from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370/gems/wasabi-2.5.0/lib/wasabi/document.rb:61:in `soap_actions'
>   from script/atmosfair.rb:28

Whereas SoapUI gives me:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns1:FlightEmission xsi:type="ns1:FlightEmissionData" xmlns:ns1="http://www.atmosfair.de/2009/07/travel" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
         <CO2>0.19</CO2>
         <offset>5.0</offset>
         <distance>1733</distance>
         <CO2PerPkm>0.0</CO2PerPkm>
         <CO2InCriticalAltitudes>0.13</CO2InCriticalAltitudes>
         <CO2RFI2>0.32</CO2RFI2>
         <CO2RFI27>0.41</CO2RFI27>
         <CO2RFI3>0.45</CO2RFI3>
         <CO2RFI4>0.59</CO2RFI4>
         <keroseneConsumption>0.06</keroseneConsumption>
         <keroseneConsumptionInCriticalAltitudes>0.04</keroseneConsumptionInCriticalAltitudes>
         <specificFuelConsumptionAverage>4.31</specificFuelConsumptionAverage>
         <offsetCO2RFI2>8.0</offsetCO2RFI2>
         <offsetCO2RFI27>11.0</offsetCO2RFI27>
         <offsetCO2RFI3>11.0</offsetCO2RFI3>
         <offsetCO2RFI4>15.0</offsetCO2RFI4>
      </ns1:FlightEmission>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Any idea, what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, by using curb instead of httpclient:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require File.expand_path(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '..', 'config', 'environment'))
require 'iconv'
require 'curb'
require 'savon'

HTTPI.adapter = :curb

   client = Savon::Client.new do |wdsl, http|
      http.headers = { "Content-Length" => "0", "Connection" => "Keep-Alive" }
      http.auth.basic "user", "password"
      wdsl.document = 'https://www.atmosfair.de:8443/services/AtmosfairEmissionService3?wsdl'
    end

    client.http.auth.ssl.verify_mode = :none

    response = client.request :wdsl, "getFlightEmission" do
       soap.body = {
         :departure => "VIE",
         :arrival => "DUB"
    }
end
```

Now everything works fine!